# What Happend to the Resources List on Central Admin SharePoint 2019

Tags: web-part, central-administration, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

Previous versions of SharePoint had the "Resources" list view web part on the Central Administration home page (far right side), but in SharePoint 2019 On-Prem its missing.  I see it in the "View Contents" but strangely I am unable to edit the Central Admin home page and add the Web Part.  The link to "Add Web Part" does nothing.  I used this often to setup shortcuts. Anyone else experience this?

Regards, Bismarck

Answer (score 2):

It was removed. Either Microsoft had telemetry indicating it wasn't used or they figured they didn't see customers using it.

Comment: Ok, I think I found something.  I created a new SP2019 Farm (Single Farm) on a VM.  The "Resources" List was displayed on the Central Admin Home Page. Great! - Then I ran the January 2019 CU (KB4461634) and Boom !!! The Resources Web Part Disappeared and I could not edit the page and add it back (the hyperlink to Add a Web part does nothing).  I was using I.E. 11, but Edge and Firefox behaved the same.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are talking about the "Resources" where you can put the links for your information. That is avaiable in SharePoint 2019, rather MSFT put two links by default their "SharePoint Server Documentation" & "SharePoint Server Updates". Still you can add more links to it. Here is what i am seeing on default.aspx of CA...[image]

If you are not seeing it then check if somebody remove the webpart (It is list view) from the default.aspx page?

BTW, this list they talk about during the release presentation of SharePoint 2019.

Comment: Yes, that is the list I'm talking about however, with a brand new install its missing on the Central admin home page and even though its there from the "View Content" , I am unable to add it. In fact, I can't add anything to the home page on Central admin.  Is this the change in SP2019 that Trevor is talking about?

Comment: no change, rather improved as i mentioned in my answer, can you edit the page? check this docs as they mentioned it is improved...https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-s-new/new-and-improved-features-in-sharepoint-server-2019 2nd heading

Comment: I can edit the page but when I click on the link "Add a Web Part" nothing happens.  The site is in the "Intranet Zone" in the browser.

Comment: I am not sure, may be try different browser or non server machine or use the fqdn in url

Comment: Ok, I think I found something.  I created a new SP2019 Farm (Single Farm) on a VM.  The "Resources" List was displayed on the Central Admin Home Page. Great! - Then I ran the January 2019 CU (KB4461634) and Boom !!! The Resources Web Part Disappeared and I could not edit the page and add it back (the hyperlink to Add a Web part does nothing).  I was using I.E. 11, but Edge and Firefox behaved the same.

Comment: Ok, so clearly January CU causing the issue. Resource list is there but jan cu is killing it.

Comment: Yes, it sure seems that way.  And the CU was only a security fix.